# Taking the date from one date and the time from another date and merging into a single date in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have four fields that are of type Date in typescript:

StartDate
StartTime
EndDate
EndTime

I need to merge the StartDate with the StartTime into a field called Start and the EndDate with the EndTime into a field called End.

I tried doing it this way and it is not working:

```
  start: new Date(e.startDate).setTime(e.startTime.getTime()),  
  end: new Date(e.endDate).setTime(e.endTime.getTime()),
```

Comment: What are supposed to be StartDate and StarTime, same with EndDate and EndTime?

Comment: @diouze All 4 of them are simply Date types in typescript. StartDate has a date that actually matters and a time that does not such as 00:00:00, StartTime has a time that actually matters and date that does not such as 1/1/0001.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't this not enough?

```
// Prepare mock data
const startDate: Date = new Date();
const startTime: Date = new Date();
const endDate: Date = new Date();
const endTime: Date = new Date();

// Doing merge
const start: Date = new Date(startDate);
start.setHours(startTime.getHours(), startTime.getMinutes(), startTime.getSeconds(), startTime.getMilliseconds());

const end: Date = new Date(endDate);
start.setHours(endTime.getHours(), endTime.getMinutes(), endTime.getSeconds(), endTime.getMilliseconds());
```